# Generic class: share a unique generic static property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I stumbled upon an issue about generic classes and generic static properties.
I have an **ActorController** class that roughly looks like this :

```
public abstract class ActorController<T> : MonoBehaviour, IActorController<T> where T : Character
{   
    public static ActorController<T> Selection { get; set; }

    public void Select(ActorController<T> clickedActorController)
    {
        if(Selection == null || !Selection.IsActing)
        {
            Selection = clickedActorController;
            onClick = Deselect;
        }
    }
}
```

And child classes that look like these (**Hero** and **Creature** inherit from **Character**) :

```
public class CreatureController : ActorController<Creature> { }
public class HeroController : ActorController<Hero> { }
```

The problem is that in the *ActorController.Select* method, when I click a **CreatureController**, *Selection* returns null if I previously selected a **HeroController**, and vice-versa ; briefly said : each child class stores its own *Selection* property, whereas I would like an unique *Selection* property shared among all child classes, that would return whichever **ActorController** got previously selected.

Thank you by advance for any information you could give me to solve or work around this.

Comment: Well `static` means it belongs to that type .. and in inherited and shared among all subtypes ... if you need it to be specific to each type then simply don't use a property in the base class but rather have each type its own static property

Comment: Can you clarify a few things for me. Why is the type of selection ActorController<T>? I would have thought it would be of type T so that a creature controller would be able to select a creature (there maybe be some covariance issues later down the line though).

Comment: @pseudoabdul The end result I want is that when I click an **ActorController**, either it be a **HeroController**, a **CreatureController** or a WhateverController, the clicked controller is stored in Selection as an **ActorController**. What is currently happening is that there is a **HeroController.Selection** storing what **HeroController** is selected, a **CreatureController.Selection** storing what **CreatureController** is selected, etc.

Comment: I think its easy to fall down the inheritance rabbit hole in Unity. I think your first option should always be the compositional approach, which is just making components and attaching them to things. So consider that. But to your problem, are you only ever wanting a single ActorController selected? A singleton pattern might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keywords makes a property or field part of the class template. Meaning that you will have that property accesible its value shared by all the instances created from that class.

"Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object." from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

I would remove the `static` from `public static ActorController<T> Selection { get; set; }` and leave it just `public ActorController<T> Selection { get; set; }`

Finally, the use of generics has no influence in the problem you are having. Its all due to the use of `static`.

Comment: Make *Selection* accessible from all instances is exactly what I want: that a **CreatureController** or a **HeroController** gets which controller is currently selected. The problem is that **HeroController** registers which **ActorController<Hero>** is selected, and **CreatureController** registers **ActorController<Creature>**. The end result I am looking for is that controllers register whichever controller is selected, no matter the sub-type.

In a nutshell, I want this condition to be true :
`HeroController.Selection == CreatureController.Selection`